# android using TimerTask and execute when screen is off

Tags: android, timertask, wakelock

In my app I want some action to be executed on specific time (not delay).
I've come to use `TimerTask`, which works fine as long as the screen is ON.
I've read in some places I have to use `wakelock` to get it work while screen is OFF.
Everywhere it is mentioned I should set my `wakelock call` on the `onReceive()`,  but `TimerTask` doesn't have this method.
Is there anywhere I can set my wakelock (to only run, I don't want the screen to be turned on) using `TimerTask` ? Or I should use a different approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read about AlarmManager? That may be better for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm totally agree with @aegean

AlarmManager is a good option.

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

http://vikinghammer.com/2012/04/22/android-use-alarmmanager-instead-of-a-service-with-a-timertask/

Regards,